# what is the best way to change status of user to log out in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, session, pdo

I am using pdo mysql in my project. What I do is on button click I update the status of the user in database into logout then I do `session_destroy();` It is working OK. But then I notice something. When I `clear cache` the user will be logged out into the system meaning will be in the login screen but the status in the database is still login. If the user has status of login he will not be allowed to login. This beats the checking of user status in my system. When the user clear cache he will not be able to login again.

What is the best way to counter this scenario?

Comment: There are no relation between **clear cache** and **database**. when you **clear cache**, it means your browser data has been destroyed. And it could not update data to your database table.

Comment: @Mustafa yes that is my problem sir. how can i over take that problem. when you clear cache session is destroyed in browser and my user will be logged out in system but the data in database still says he is logged in meaning he cant login unless the database will be altered in a different way.

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: *"If the user has status of login he will not be allowed to login"* - Remove that limitation. Problem solved.

Comment: @Mike i am having that limitation so that the user will be logged in only once..I mean 1 user will be logged in in one pc only

Comment: How are you storing that they're logged in via the database? An assumption would be you have a column named `loggedIn` which variates between 0 - 1 for offline / online? Ideally need to see your setup to give you an acrual answer

Comment: @option yes i have that just like what you said on click of button just before `session_destroy();` i update the value to `0` for not update

Comment: And is the query actually running because it sounds like it isn't if its still showing online. Need to see your code really...

Comment: "*i am having that limitation so that the user will be logged in only once*" - So if a new session starts, kill the old one.